# include extensions in haskell-stack conf file

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to add ViewPatterns extensions to my build and currently I do it by adding the following lines to package.yaml

```
ghc-options:
- -Wall
- -XViewPatterns
```

I get a warning:

```
Warning: Instead of 'ghc-options: -XViewPatterns' use 'extensions:
ViewPatterns'
```

But, when I add an `extensions` field to package.yaml, I get the following:

```
WARNING: Ignoring unknown field "extensions" in package description
```

Also, I could not find any definition of `extensions` in the official stack documentation.

Comment: How stupid of hpack to suggest a field name that doesn't exist. I opened https://github.com/sol/hpack/issues/574

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do not confuse stack with [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack).

`package.yaml` is actually read by hpack.
But `stack build` command implicitly calls hpack to automatically convert into a cabal file, which may make you confused.

Anyway, to specify extensions in package.yaml,
use `default-extensions`:

```
default-extensions: ViewPatterns
```

Comment: When I do this I get `Unrecognized field in ProjectAndConfigMonoid: default-extensions`, Is there something I need to include to make that field valid?

Comment: I can't diagnose by that error message. Can you post a question with the entire content of package.yaml?

Comment: I can confirm this does work in 2024 with stack v2.13.1.

Answer (score 0):

`extensions:` is currently unsupported by stack, see follow-ups in this github [issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3137).

Comment: The issue you referred to is about `stack.yaml` whereas OP is updating `package.yaml`. Not the same thing.